# Is there a way to have your own namespace named 'x.System'

Tags: c#

```
namespace Company.Product.System
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
...
```

This generates compiler errors because now Visual Studio can't find `System.Collections.Generic;`. Is there a way to workaround this? I don't want to hear about if this is a bad idea not, this decision comes from above me and I have very little choice in the matter.

Comment: Why don't you put your using statements outside of the namespace?

Comment: what the used of opening bracket above namespace sir? @cost

Comment: @ScottChamberlain That's a good idea, one that's obvious but didn't occur to me. The code was generated by a tool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options, put the using statement outside of the namespace

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Company.Product.System
{
...
```

Or add the `global::` prefix to the namespace, this forces it to use the root instead of assuming you are wanting to use `Company.Product.System.Collections`

```
namespace Company.Product.System
{
using global::System;
using global::System.Collections.Generic;
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Either move your using directives *outside* of the namespace block or use the the [global namespace alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx) like so:

```
namespace Company.System
{
    using global::System.Collections.Generic;
}
```